# how to change the price filter in Magento

Tags: price, ce-1.9.1.0, frontend

Now I am working on `magento-1.9.1`. We all know Magento has default price filter. In stead of the default filter, I want to use a slider.

actual code: `view.phtml`,

```
<?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
 <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
    <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
        <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
   <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

filter.phtml:

```
<ol>

<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

   <?php echo $_item->getLabel();?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

My code is, `view.phtml`:

```
<?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php
                            // get display attribute code
                            $attributeModel = $_filter->getAttributeModel();
                            if($attributeModel) {
                                $attr_code = $attributeModel->getAttributeCode();

                            }
                ?>

                <?php //echo $attr_code;?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <?php if($attr_code == 'price'){?>
                        <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                        <dd>
                        <input id="range_1" type="text" name="range_1" value="1;<?php echo $maxPrice+100;?>" data-type="double" data-step="1" data-postfix="$" data-from="<?php echo $minPrice;?>" data-to="<?php echo $maxPrice;?>" data-hasgrid="true" />
                        </dd>

                    <?php }else { ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

my jquery is,

```
$j('#range_1').ionRangeSlider();
```

what I want is, the products should change when I change the price range in the slider. I don’t know how to give the filter URL to the slider. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to catch the range of the ionRangeSlider(). By Using This Function you can catch the slider range

```
$j('#range_1').on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    from = $this.data("from"),
    to = $this.data("to");

console.log(from + " - " + to);
 });
```

Here from and to is the price range of the slider. Now replace console.log with

```
window.location('<?php echo $this->getUrl().'?price=from-to'?>') ;
```